# Bold the character in the first occurence of a string using split in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, split

I'm trying to bold the text in the first occurence of string, matching the input query  but the character is getting bold on every occurence in the string.

Input : "9"
Current Output:**99**8**9**45**9**
Expected output:**9**989459

```
 var  display = "9989459" 
 var input = "9"
 var splitArr = display.split(new RegExp(`(${input})`, 'gi'));
 var result =  splitArr.map((parts,i) => parts === input ? <b key={i}>{parts}</b> : parts)
 return <span> {result} </span>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The `<b>` is JSX and not a string.

Comment: If i use that delimiter , the characters after that are not present in a array

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that it's rendering with that bold tag wrapping around the search query , like `<b>9</b>989459`

Comment: Ok, try ``var rx = new RegExp(`(${input})`, 'gi'); var splitArr = display.split(rx, 2); splitArr.push( display.substr(rx.lastIndex + splitArr.join("").length) )``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow , It worked .Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

```
const target = '9'
const str = '9989459'
const index = str.indexOf(target)

const parts = [a.slice(0, index), `<b>${a.slice(index, index+1 )}</b>`, a.slice(index + 1)]

// [ '', '<b>9</b>', '989459' ]
```

Comment: No, Its rendering with that b tag , like `<b>9</b>989459`

Comment: Yes, this is just the example code to extract and transform the original string. Use the resulting array as you wish, for instance to generate html in directly or with any framework